# CSS Responsiveness recommendation?

Tags: css, html, web

I just got into the annoying part of CSS, the responsiveness, my big question is

Should I work media queries like this: min-width: xxx to max-width: xxx or simply work with a min-width?

Because I've seen a few sites that whenever you resize the browser or enter from your phone, it won't change from 350px to 600px, it pretty much stays the same unless you go for above 1000px or something...

What's the best standar? or what can you guys recommend me when trying to make it responsive, use exact queries like this: min-width: xxx to max-width: xxx or what?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you will find that `max-width` is usually sufficient, it really depends on how accurate you want to be.

[Bootstrap 3.0](http://getbootstrap.com) has some fundamental media queries in it's CSS and I either recommend using it, or studying it.

Answer (score 0):

As Zanderwar mentions, it depends on how many breakpoints you want to have.

Personally, when I build something simple and I don´t want to use the whole of Bootstrap, I just copy their breakpoints.

Notice that they don't use max-width as the next min-width size will act as breakpoint.

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

You can read more about it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries).

Also, notice that most CSS frameworks tend to push the idea of mobile-first, designing for little screens first and adapting to tablet and big screens after.

Hope it helps!